# Account Not Blocking when invalid password entered many times

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am acquiring an access token from Azure AD B2C via https://login.windows.net/{tenantID}/oauth2/token using the password grant passing in username and password.
Resource = https://graph.microsoft.com/&client_id={clientId}&&grant_type=password&username="{username}"&password="{password}"&scope=openid"

The token is being returned but I when I purposely use an invalid password many times my expectation was that it would block the account and it does not.

Is this normal behaviour ?